# Instrumenting AWS async client sdk threadpool with Micrometer

Tags: spring-micrometer, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I'm trying to understand the best way to instrument the default thread pool executor used by AWS async client. [Source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/58451426c75522cb26db2e48f10a1d225c93e6c8/core/sdk-core/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/core/client/builder/SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java#L383). We are using Micrometer for tracking all metrics.

I aim to understand if I should use a custom thread pool executor or if the default one is good enough.

My current code is as follows (and it works as expected):

```
//use the same thread pool executor as the aws sdk but instrument it.
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
int corePoolSize = Math.max(8, processors);
int maxPoolSize = Math.max(64, processors * 2);
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize,
                10, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1_000),
                new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                        .threadNamePrefix("sdk-async-response").build());
// Allow idle core threads to time out
executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);

var instrumentedExecutor = ExecutorServiceMetrics.monitor(meterRegistry,
                executor,
                "instrumented-ddb-executor");

return DynamoDbAsyncClient.builder()
                .asyncConfiguration(b -> b.advancedOption(FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR, instrumentedExecutor))
                .build();
```

I feel there is a simpler way but cannot find it. Is there a simpler way to instrument without redefining the default executor?

Answer (score 1):

You can override default metric collector for micrometer: this is my implementation: https://gist.github.com/PatrykGala/e4aec004eb55cd8cbdee328f217771c7